# Why does my variable not live long enough?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a simple piece of code that is supposed to read a file into a vector by lines

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::fs::File;

fn file_to_vec(filename: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, io::Error> {
    let mut file = try!(File::open(filename));
    let mut string = String::new();
    try!(file.read_to_string(&mut string));
    string.replace("\r", "");

    let data: Vec<&str> = string.split('\n').collect();

    Ok(data)
}

fn main() {}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `string` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:27
   |
10 |     let data: Vec<&str> = string.split('\n').collect();
   |                           ^^^^^^ does not live long enough
...
13 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 4:1...
  --> src/main.rs:4:1
   |
4  | / fn file_to_vec(filename: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, io::Error> {
5  | |     let mut file = try!(File::open(filename));
6  | |     let mut string = String::new();
7  | |     try!(file.read_to_string(&mut string));
...  |
12 | |     Ok(data)
13 | | }
   | |_^
```

Why do I keep getting this error? How do I fix this? I imagine that it has something to do with the `split` method.

I could return the string and then split it into a `Vec` in the main function, but I really want to return a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `string` is created in your function and will be destroyed when the function returns. The vector you want to return contains slices of `string`, but those will not be valid outside of your function.

If you're not terribly worried about performance, you can return a `Vec<String>` from your function. You just have to return type to `Result<Vec<String>, io::Error>` and change the line

```
let data: Vec<&str> = string.split('\n').collect();
```

to

```
let data: Vec<String> = string.split('\n').map(String::from).collect();
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something trivial. I guess you have to change the Vec type to String in the last line as well.

Comment: @ehsisthatsweird You're right, I missed that. Incidentally, the type annotation should not be necessary here, type inference can handle this case.